# How can I hide workspaces from application list in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

I just want to remove the red marked part from my app drawer. Is it possible to remove ?

[image]

Comment: i want to make ubutu aplication list style like mac os completly? and i dont need to disply workspace window in application list - @24601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) by JustPerfection allows plenty of costomization, including hiding selectively these elements.